# SQL 2 different column in one column

Tags: sql

i want to know how can i do this i have 3 columns 1 column is same NAME 2 -column have different date and 3 column is diffetent numbers

```
Column1  Column2      Column3
EMIN     01/01/2021   5
EMIN     05/08/1984   2
FUAD     05/02/2022   5
FUAD     06/07/1991   2
```

I want if Column3 = 5 write Column2 data to new YEAR1 column  but if Column3 = 2 it writes to new column name YEAR 2
like that

```
Column1  YEAR1        YEAR2
EMIN     01/01/2021   05/08/1984
FUAD     05/02/2022   06/07/1991
```

Comment: I don't follow what you are trying to do.  Can you try to clarify the explanation?  Is the data sample data or the results?  Both are helpful.  If one column is "Name", why isn't that in the sample data?

Comment: Please just mention the output you want. And also please mention dbms name you are using

Comment: in column 3 (5-means fake 2-means true) I want to know if its true when is Emin s birthday date

Comment: Please edit the answer and put your desired output. is it EMIN 05/08/1984 true and EMIN     01/01/2021 false?

Comment: Is that sample table data? Add some more rows, to make things clearer. Also specify the expected result. [mcve].

Comment: Can you read (and do something with the comment) from Kazi from Apr 8 2021 ?   And, please, tell us what you tried to solve this on your own. in this past  2 years

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want a self-join on your table:

```
SELECT
  T1.Column1,
  T1.Column2 AS YEAR1,
  T2.Column2 AS YEAR2
FROM
  MyTable AS T1
  JOIN MyTable AS T2 ON T1.Column1 = T2.Column1
WHERE
  T1.Column3 = 5 AND
  T2.Column3 = 2
```

In my answer, I used table name `MyTable`. You probably need to replace it with the actual table name.

You could keep the aliases `T1` and `T2`, but you could change those as well. Just make sure to rename all occurrences correctly.

I also assumed that your table will always contain matching rows (for each row where `Column3 = 5` there also exists another row with the same value for `Column1`, but where `Column3 = 2`).

Being able to join table data is a primary skill when querying databases with SQL. I strongly encourage you to learn more about it if you need to do more querying like this in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You have just edited your request, so it seems that after more than two years you are still looking for an answer?

First f all, you'll have to group by column1, in order to get one result row per column1. Then aggregate conditionally.

You still haven't told us your DBMS. The following query should run in abour every RDBMS, though:

```
select
  column1,
  max(case when column3 = 5 then column2 end) as year1,
  max(case when column3 = 2 then column2 end) as year2
from mytable
group by column1
order by column1;
```

If your DBMS supports the standard SQL filter clause then you can get this slightly more readable thus:

```
select
  column1,
  max(column2) filter (where column3 = 5) as year1,
  max(column2) filter (where column3 = 2) as year2
from mytable
group by column1
order by column1;
```

Comment: This actually is a very nice answer if there would be "duplicate" rows for the same `Column1` and `Column3` combinations. In my own answer, I assumed there were no duplicates. So your solution is more complex, but more correct and more robust as well. I also guess that it's up to the OP which aggregate function should be used for which column; it could be min/max, max/min or min/min as well... ;)

Comment: @Bart Hofland: I don't assume any duplicates either. And yoe are right, it doesn't matter, whether to use `MIN` or `MAX` on that one row in question. For the query with the filter clause, we could even use `ANY_VALUE` which might show the intention more clearly, while we must not use this function in my first query in order not to pick nulls mistakenly.